# Is this a memory leak?

Tags: c#, events

I have a class shown below. Server instance holds reference to listener instance. Listener holds reference to server instance through event delegate. Will this prevent GC from collecting server instance? If so, how to break this cycle? Should I implement IDisposable or override Finalize method or do something else?

```
public class Server
    {        
        public Listener Listener { get; private set; }        

        public Server(Listener listener)
        {
            Listener = listener;
            Listener.ClientChannelConnected += new EventHandler<ClientChannelConnectedArgs>(listener_ClientChannelConnected);
        }        

        void listener_ClientChannelConnected(object sender, ClientChannelConnectedArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The .NET garbage collector is smart enough to resolve circular references.

Comment: I didnt' know that :(
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, I found that this type of code consistently leaks in .net, and had to be careful to -= the event handler. It is true that the memory is released *eventually*, but in practice you want to clean up after yourself sooner than that.

Also, never *ever* use a lambda expression to handle an event, as you will never have a reference back to that object.

Comment: This would happen if something else still had a reference to the object holding the delegate list. In this case, if listener was still used elsewhere even after you are done with the instance of Server. That's probably why you saw them be kept in memory for way longer.

Comment: It is also ok to use Lambda's when the object you subscribe the event on will be disposed at the same time you'd want your event to be disposed. When the producer of an event gets disposed, it loses its references to the event handlers his events were holding, therefore, those objects can in turn be Garbage Collected.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this article about memory leaks](http://madgeek.com/Articles/Leaks/Leaks.en.html#Events). Sometimes you should use -=.